# Scala JAR file; can't find or load main class in a JAR file

Tags: java, scala, jar, sbt

I can't figure out why I can't run my JAR files. I have been looking for hours, but I still have no clue.

Originally I need it for my Scala Spark data science thesis project, since I need to run the JAR files on a Spark Cluster, but even a very basic example doesn't work.

What I am trying to do, but that even fails is:

My test code:

```
object superSimpleTest {
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  System.out.println("I'm a JAR")
 }
}
```

I build the JAR file using Intellij as follows:

File -> Project Structure -> Artifacts -> + -> JAR with "from modules with dependencies". From the pop-up window I change the manifest output path to resources. After that I go to Build -> Build Artifact -> Build

[image: Create JAR module]
[image: JAR module overview]

My manifest looks like this:

---

- Manifest-Version: 1.0
- Main-Class: superSimpleTest

---

When I then run in terminal: java -jar JARNAME.jar I get the error:

*Error: Could not find or load main class superSimpleTest*

Honestly, at this point, I have no clue what I am doing wrong since the code runs fine within Intellij.

Someone that can help me go forward?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it works with

*mvn clean compile assembly:single* with the Maven Assembly plugin.